# How do you calculate the fugacity for a Van der Waals gas at low pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

How can the fugacity of this state equation:
$$pV/(nRT) =1+ [b-a/(RT)] p/(RT)$$ be calculated? I've already tried to divide the pressure of that by that of an ideal gas, but somehow don't get far with it. How would I calculate the fugacity coefficient here?

Answer (score 0):

$$RTd\ln{f}=vdp$$where v is the molar volume.  So, $$RTd\ln{(f/p)}=\left(v-\frac{RT}{p}\right)dp$$ subject to the condition that (f/p)=1 at p=0